# How to integrate Angular 2 (angular-cli) app into Sails.js

Tags: angular, sails.js, angular-cli

I need to integrate the app generated by **angular-cli** into **Sails.js**. I come from php background so I am new to both these frameworks.

1. How do I set them up as one?
2. How do I run `ng serve` and/or `sails lift`?
3. How do I manage Angular routes vs Sails routes?

Thanks.

Comment: I my opinion manage angular and sails as seperate that is dont combine frontend and backend. When u want single application create final dist folder in angular-cli and place it inside sails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following blog can help you to integrate sails with angular 2
http://sharpten.com/blog/2016/02/02/integrating-angular-2-with-sails-js.html

you can download code from 
https://github.com/xmaestro/sails-angular2

Comment: The above is out of date. angular-cli switched build systems from systemjs to webpack.

Comment: This tutorial and repo is a great starting point, for your View. `sails lift` runs, error-free. Displays the sample Angular 4 app.

Answer (score 0):

See this [skeleton for Sails and Angular 2](https://github.com/Giancarlo1974/SailsAngular)

It's integrates also the grunt task for develope automation

The client is Angular 4 (It's quite the same as Angular2) + Bootstrap 4

The server is Node JS (it's use Sails as MVC framework)